# Ebean. Specifying column both as @Column and @JoinColumn throws an error

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.5

I am trying to specify one-to-many relation to the same table. This is what I have now:

```
public class User extends Model {
    .....

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    public Long parentId;

    .....    

    // Relationships

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    public List<User> children;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    public User parent;
}
```

`parent_id` is used as foreign key. And I need this column to present as an attribute of the User instance:

```
user.parentId
```

But specifying the `parent_id` column as foreign key (@JoinColumn) does not allow to specify it as attribute (@Column). It throw the following error:

```
[CompletionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ERROR: column "parent_id" specified more than once ...
```

How to handle this?

Comment: That's because your `User` model maps the foreign key column `parent_id` twice, which is not allowed. To avoid this redundancy, just remove the first mapping `public Long parentId;` and access `parentId` via `parent.id`.

Comment: It is a bad solution to access `parentId` through `parent.id`. In that case it will fetch `parent` from DB, but I do not need `parent`. I just need `parentId` which I should be able to access because it is a column like many others.  The problem is unnecessary DB queries.

Comment: You may also solve this issue by extending the `@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")` annotation with `@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)`.

Comment: `parent.id. In that case it will fetch parent from DB` -- no it won't actually. That traversal won't invoke lazy loading.

Comment: What version of Ebean are you using?  (Current is 9.3.1)

Comment: I am using 7.6.1. Added through `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.2")`